# Can't dump mysql table with corrupt index

Tags: mysql

One of the tables in my database is having an issue with indexing, I was advised to

1. backup the table,
2. remove the index, and
3. create a new one of the same name using the same columns.

I can't even move to step 2 because I can't backup the table. When I try to export it I get the error below:

> mysqldump: Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
>   when dumping table `data_1_2019_11` at row: 1622537

I've tried changing the connection, read and write timeouts but it doesn't seem to be working in my case.

Is there another way I can do this? To backup the table? I want to ask if its safe for me to just move on to step 2 and step 3? Would really be nice to know how to fix the issue as well though for future references.

Thank you

Comment: Is that an InnoDB table? Can you share the table definition (SHOW CREATE TABLE)? If innodb then you can copy the data directory and put it somewhere safe, use Percona Server for MySQL with innodb_corrupt_table_action warn or salvage in conjunction with innodb_force_recovery 1-3 (do not proceed with 4-6 unless you have a physical copy of the data).

Comment: Have you checked partial backup? for example 500 rows per export

Comment: @jerichorivera yes its innodb, shit its already on 6, mysql wouldn't run on 1 to 3 so i tried up to 6 and it started running and then that was the time i was able to do a mysql check on the tables and saw that the table i mentioned was having an issue with indexing. Shiit is there no way to salvage it now?

Comment: @Hamid no i haven't tried that, ill see if that's possible i will let you guys know

Comment: @jerichorivera hi, sorry so i checked again and it was at 4 not 6, i tried to check if i can get the server running at 3 and i was able to so its at 3 now